# Assign using Active Assignment Rule being ignored with UpdateSingleSalesforceObject

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, leads, assignment-rules, sales-cloud

The AMPscript function `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` ignores Assignment Rules when Leads are created or updated. Is there any way to assign the assignment rule when a lead is updated via `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject`?

It looks like there is an [AssignmentRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_assignmentruleheader.htm) when using an API which essentially what the Marketing Cloud Connector is using via managed package. But it does not look like the [AssignmentRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_assignmentruleheader.htm) is exposed via AMPscript. Since it is not exposed via AMPscript, I cannot find a way to apply the assignment rule. Any way around this?