# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Run Lead assignment rules

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a list of leads that I want to re-run lead assignment rules for. (This list changes but if owner ID = X I want to activate the LAR)

Is there a method within SFMC to activate Lead assignment rules? Either through ampscript or SSJS or Journey builder?

Or would I be better served using APEX/Process builder?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, nothing that I know of is available to activate lead assignment rules in SFMC. In some cases, SalesCloud/ServiceCloud actually ignores some lead assignment rules when updated in SFMC because the lead record is updated via API and for whatever reason CRM doesn’t recognize it as a record update for lead assignments.

I asked a similar question here: [Assign using Active Assignment Rule being ignored with UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279715/assign-using-active-assignment-rule-being-ignored-with-updatesinglesalesforceobj)

I ended up using Process Builder to kick off a process when the lead record gets updated which match certain parameters.

Comment: If I use the upsert function, write to a DE, then have that DE entry journey builder, have journey builder check to see if there is a record ELSE, create a new lead, wouldn't that new lead go through the LAR?

Comment: For creating new leads it should work, but I had assumed your original question was to re-run assignment rules for existing leads (you mentioned “re-run lead assignment rules”).  In my experience, new leads didn’t have any issues with lead assignment but only with re-assigning with an update to the lead record.

Comment: @JacksonChen - From my observation, LAR's dont execute for new Leads created via SFMC forms as well. Can you confirm if this is the case?

Comment: @gutsyfella from my experience if you’re using the `CreateSalesforceObject` AMPscript function LAR should work for new leads. Assume you’re using CloudPages in SFMC? How is the lead created on Sales/Service Cloud?